# discord.js guildMemberAdded not firing

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make it so when a user joins, the bot sends a message in a certain channel. I saw that you needed to enable some things in the developer portal, so I did that but it still doesn't run when a user joins, I tried printing when the user joins but it still wont do anything.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', joinMember => {
    console.log("a")
    const joinChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'logs')
    let joinEmbed = {
        title : `Welcome to ${client.guild.name}, @${joinMember.tag}`,
        color : embedColor
    }
    joinChannel.send({embeds : [joinEmbed]})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Guild member related events are [privileged intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#privileged-intents).

It means that you have to turn it on at your bot page.

[image]

User presence related events are also privileged, and message content related events are also privileged after April 30.